# Walking a huge game tree

Tags: search, haskell, timeout

I have a game tree that is too big to walk in its entirety.

How can I write a function that will evaluate the tree until a time limit or depth limit is reached?

Comment: Consider algorithms such as A*, min-max, alpha-beta, and the recent GOAP.

Comment: Heath, I currently use a minimax algorithm. But on larger trees it takes too long.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would help to have a bit more detail, I think. Also, you raise two entirely separate issues--do you want both limits applied simultaneously, or are you looking for how to do each independently? That said, in rough terms:

- **Time limit**: This is clearly impossible without using `IO`, to start with. Assuming your game tree traversal function is largely pure you'd probably prefer not to intertwine it with a bunch of time-tracking that determines control flow. I think the simplest thing here is probably to have the traversal produce a stream of progressively better results, place each "best result so far" into an `MVar` or such, and run it on a separate thread. If the time limit is reached, just kill the thread and take the current value from the `MVar`.
- **Depth limit**: The most thorough way to do this would be to simply perform a breadth-first search, wouldn't it? If that's not viable for whatever reason, I don't think there's any better solution than the obvious one of simply keeping a counter to indicate the current depth and not continuing deeper when the maximum is reached. Note that this is a case where the code can potentially be tidied up using a Reader-style monad, where each recursive call is wrapped in something like `local (subtract 1)`.

Comment: For the depth limit, instead of keeping a depth counter, use an auxiliary pruning function? e.g. `take` prunes a list to a specified length.

Comment: @dave4420: True, though of course that's just moving the counter somewhere else. If the structure can be generated lazily it amounts to the same thing and the pruning function is nicer. Now that you mention it, I probably would do it that way at first, but since the question here is motivated in part by limited resources it might be necessary to combine the functions to avoid having the entire pruned tree in memory at once.

Answer (score 6):

The [`timeout`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.3.1.0/doc/html/System-Timeout.html) function in the base package allows you to kill a computation after a certain period. Interleaving `timeout` with a stream of increasingly deeper results, such that the most recent result is stored in an `MVar` is a relatively common trick for search problems in Haskell.

Comment: Ha, I suggested doing exactly this without realizing that `timeout` already existed. Oops... should have figured, since it's a pretty obvious approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a lazy writer monad for your traversal, generating a list of improving answers. Now you've simplified your problem somewhat, to just taking the first "good enough" or "best so far" result from the list by some criteria. On top of that you can use the `timeout` trick that dons described, or any other approach you think appropriate...